# Can i identify "Question words"(who, how, when...) in a string using spacy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I have a string

```py
a = "Hello my name is Amar. How can I help you?"
doc = nlp(a)
for tok in doc: 
    print(tok.text, "-->",tok.dep_,"-->", tok.pos_)
```

This code is printing all text, dependency and pos of string.
I want to identify question word "How" in string.

Comment: Do you need more assistance with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to find a token(s) with `tok.dep_ == 'advmod'` and `tok.pos_ == 'ADV'` then use

```py
[tok.text for tok in doc if tok.dep_ == 'advmod' and tok.pos_ == 'ADV']
```

This prints `['How']`.

Comment: advmod words aren't always question words. https://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/advmod.html

Comment: Correct, but OP did not say "extract all question words", but "*I want to identify question word "How"*" and the `tok.dep_ == 'advmod'` and `tok.pos_ == 'ADV'` differentiate it from the rest of the tokens in the given text. If the task is more specific, let OP precise the question. If the task is getting all words that are "like" [interrogative words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word), OP can use `[tok.text for tok in doc if tok.lemma_ in ['which', 'what', 'whose', 'who', 'whom', 'where', 'whither', 'whence', 'when', 'how', 'why', 'whether']]`.

Comment: Also, if the interrogative words needs to be extracted only if the sentence ends with `?`, the `[tok.text for tok in doc if tok.lemma_ in ['which', 'what', 'whose', 'who', 'whom', 'where', 'whither', 'whence', 'when', 'how', 'why', 'whether'] and doc.text[tok.sent.end_char-1] == '?']` will help.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to stick to the basics for this?

```
a = "Hello my name is Amar. How can I help you?"
Space = a.find(" ")
Q= a[:Space]
```